# How Can I Rewrite Dynamic PHP URLs to Static HTML Pages Keeping the Querystring as Filename

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried multiple different things to get this to work and have hit a wall.  Here's some example URLs:

```
domain.com/pagelist.php?pageNum_rs_Quote=4&totalRows_rs_Quote=69&person_name=&qtext=&subject=3
domain.com/pagelist.php?person_name=Aristotle
domain.com/pagelist.php?subject=1
```

I want to change it to this:

```
domain.com/pageNum_rs_Quote=4&totalRows_rs_Quote=69&person_name=&qtext=&subject=3.html
domain.com/person_name=Aristotle.html
domain.com/subject=1.html
```

I have static html versions of those pages and I don't need php for the site.  I do need to keep the file pagelist.php though as it is a static file on the site also.

So far the best I've been able to get is domain.com/.html?subject=1 or domain.com/pagelist.phpsubject=1

Basically, get rid of pagelist.php? and add .html to the end of the filename.

Comment: Do you mean that files with that names are ready on server folders, and you want the redirect rule from the request to the .php to the .html version ???

Comment: Yes and no.  I have the static files but like I mentioned I need to do more than just go from .php to .html.  I need to remove the ? and the portion that says pagelist.php.

I originally had files like this pagelist.php?subject=1 but they were static files not dynamic so I couldn't figure out how to display them without just removing the pagelist.php and ? and making them static html files by renaming them all.

Comment: the question is, if you do `ls` on some folder of your server, do you actualy have a file named pageNum_rs_Quote=4&totalRows_rs_Quote=69&person_name=&qtext=&subject=3.html there?

Comment: Yes the files are there.